# Converting UTC date to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I am trying to convert NSDate with UTC to NSString. However it returns wrong value. How can I directly cast the date to string.

Below you can see the problem better:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:etkinlikDate];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

//Optionally for time zone conversions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];
```

Answer (score 1):

set `NSTimeZone` in `NSDateFormatter` like this :

```
[dateFormater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```